# lineHeight incorrect in Jetpack Compose Texts when changing fontSize

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What is the correct way to set font size in Jetpack Compose so that text is readable across multiple lines?

At the risk of sounding like an obvious question, the official answer (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/style-text#change-size) doesn't seem complete, as it has problems with line height.

For example:

```
@Composable
fun Heading(text: String) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        fontSize = 30.sp,
    )
}
```

...and then using with `Heading("heading test ".repeat(20))` produces this:

[image: heading text repeated at font size 30]

You can see the text lines are slightly closer than is comfortable to read. And if I increase the fontSize further, say to 100.sp, the effect is much more pronounced:

[image: heading text repeated with font size of 100.sp, all crunched up]

Also, there is the opposite problem at small font sizes. Here's the same thing at 6.sp:

[image: enormous padding at 6.sp]

...where there is enormous padding (relative to the font size) between the lines.

So what's the correct way to specify font size so that the lines are the right height?

This doesn't work:

```
@Composable
fun Heading(text: String) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        lineHeight = TextUnit.Unspecified
    )
}
```

I could set the lineHeight to the same as the fontSize each time, but that seems like I'd be trampling all over something that should be automatic. Plus I'm not even sure the line height *should* be equal to the font size, there is potentially quite a complex calculation needed depending on font styles etc.

Comment: By default, the text looks fine to me. (No overlapping for large font and no large gap for small font). Is this a custom font?

Comment: @Abhimanyu no not a custom font. The 30 SP default would have the top of the 'd' clashing with the bottom of the 'g' above it, were they to coincide horizontally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the `TextStyle`. If you look at the source of `Text`, you can see there are two arguments that can affect `lineHeight`:

```kotlin
Text(
    ...,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
)
```

When `lineHeight` is unspecified, as in your case, compose takes `lineHeight` from `style`, which is `LocalTextStyle` by default. `LocalTextStyle` is then set by most of the material design components. `MaterialTheme` sets it to `Typography.bodyLarge`, which looks like [this](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/59fdc57061e73a4ac5ee4d585ac897ccc6f1f180:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/tokens/TypographyTokens.kt;l=26) by default:

```kotlin
val BodyLarge =
    DefaultTextStyle.copy(
        fontFamily = TypeScaleTokens.BodyLargeFont,
        fontWeight = TypeScaleTokens.BodyLargeWeight,
        fontSize = TypeScaleTokens.BodyLargeSize,
        lineHeight = TypeScaleTokens.BodyLargeLineHeight,
        letterSpacing = TypeScaleTokens.BodyLargeTracking,
    )

internal object TypeScaleTokens {
    ...
    val BodyLargeLineHeight = 24.0.sp
}
```

This means that every text you place inside `MaterialTheme {}` will have `lineHeight = 24.sp` unless you change it somehow. How you can change it?

1. Don't use hardcoded `fontSize` but rather some predifined `TextStyle` from your theme that comes with proper `lineHeight`. As I said, most material components, like `Button`, will set appropriate text style for you.

```kotlin
Text(
    text = "Text",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge,
)
```

2. Remove the line height from `bodyLarge` text style (and possibly others) in your theme.

```kotlin
MaterialTheme(
    typography = Typography(
        bodyLarge = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            lineHeight = TextUnit.Unspecified,
        ),
    )
) {}
```

3. Set `LocalTextStyle` to text style with unspecified line height where you need it.

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalTextStyle provides TextStyle.Default,
) {
    Text(text = "heading test ".repeat(20), fontSize = 100.sp)
    Text(text = "heading test ".repeat(20), fontSize = 6.sp)
}
```

4. Set text style of each `Text` composable you don't want to use the one from `LocalTextStyle`.

```kotlin
Text(
    text = "heading test ".repeat(20),
    fontSize = 100.sp,
    style = TextStyle.Default,
)
Text(
    text = "heading test ".repeat(20),
    fontSize = 6.sp,
    style = TextStyle.Default,
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, and for the careful research. But... what an insane amount of work is needed for something tiny! Seems absolutely absurd.